# OpenVPN service mode connection from Windows 8 fails after shutdown

Tags: openvpn, windows-8

I have an openvpn server that works fine, but have an issue on a Windows 8.1 station that is configured in service mode. I have installed it already to more Win8 PCs but not in service mode.

The connection gets established properly, if I do a shutdown after I turn it on again it won't start the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that lead me to the solution was that interestingly after I did a restart and not shutdown, the connection has established at startup.

The problem comes from hybrid shutdown, implemented as default shutdown from Windows 8. To turn this feature off I have followed these steps:

1. Search for `Power Settings` from the Start screen.
2. Click on `Change what the power buttons do.`
3. Click `Change settings that are currently unavailable.`
4. If prompted, enter the Administrator password to change the User Account Controls.
5. Under Shutdown settings, uncheck the box next to `Turn on fast startup (recommended.)`
6. Click `Save changes`, then restart.

Description of steps taken from:
http://www.maketecheasier.com/disable-hybrid-boot-and-shutdown-in-windows-8/